# Combine two entities and get the data

Tags: hibernate, jpa

I have two entity classes FlcDrawingRequests and FlcDrawingRequestStats .
get the data from two tables i try to get  the data from both tables using below query.unable to fetch the data.could you please any one help me on this.

```
 private static final String querystat = "select dr, ds from 
 FlcDrawingRequests AS dr,FlcDrawingRequestStats AS ds where dr.id=ds.request_id";
```

below are the two entity classes

FlcDrawingRequests

```
@Entity(name = "FlcDrawingRequests")
@Table(name = "drawing_requests", catalog = FlcWsDao.DB_SCHEMA_NAME)
public class FlcDrawingRequests {

    @Id
    private String id;
    @Column(name = "creation_time", nullable = false, updatable = false)
    private Date creation_time;
    @Column(name = "drawing_spec_format", length = 16)
    private String drawing_spec_format;
    @Column(name = "end_time")
    private Date end_time;
}
```

FlcDrawingRequests

```
@Entity(name = "FlcDrawingRequestStats")
@Table(name = "drawing_request_stats", catalog = FlcWsDao.DB_SCHEMA_NAME)
public class FlcDrawingRequestStats {
    @Id
    private String request_id;
    @Column(name = "bb", length = 11)
    private Integer bb;
    @Column(name = "car_offset_g", length = 11)
    private Integer car_offset_g;
    @Column(name = "car_sling_type", length = 32)
    private String car_sling_type;
    @Column(name = "car_type", length = 16)
    private String car_type;
    @Column(name = "ch", length = 11)
    private Integer ch;
}
```

below is the Query execution:

```
StringBuilder queryBuilder = new StringBuilder(querystat);
System.out.println("startDate--->" + startDate);
Query query =getEntityManager().createQuery(queryBuilder.toString());
System.out.println("query.list();--->" + query.getResultList().size());
return query.getResultList();
```

Comment: @veljkost u have any idea on this.

Comment: You don't know JPA and Hibernate, right? So maybe you should start reading a book or a tutorial like: https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/tutorial/partpersist.htm#BNBPY

Comment: @SimonMartinelli ok thanks.will read in free time.now don'nt have time Could you please provide me the solution.

Comment: @arjun You wrote all your code but did'nt yet ask a question. What is the expectedbehaviour, what is the observed behaviour?

Comment: i am expecting i need to get two tables data when i execute the mentioned Query(select dr, ds from 
 FlcDrawingRequests AS dr,FlcDrawingRequestStats AS ds where dr.id=ds.request_id) . i am getting only FlcDrawingRequests data .

Answer (score 0):

```
 private static final String querystat = "SELECT dr, ds FROM 
 FlcDrawingRequests dr,FlcDrawingRequestStats ds WHERE dr.id LIKE ds.request_id";
```

and the result must be stored in `List<Object[2]>` so you must have:

```
List<Object[2]> result=query.getResultList();
```

So here you have a list of table with size equals to two, each element in the list contains two Objects the first is FlcDrawingRequests and the second is FlcDrawingRequestStats.